# C# Find day first time and last time in a range of dates

Tags: c#, datetime, find

I have a file which look like this (list is sorted):

```
2013-05-02 07:45:15
2013-05-02 09:25:01
2013-05-02 18:15:15
2013-05-04 08:45:15
2013-05-04 17:45:35
```

I would like to get only first and last time of each day in that list, so it means I would like to get this:

```
2013-05-02 07:45:15
2013-05-02 18:15:15
2013-05-04 08:45:15
2013-05-04 17:45:35
```

What would be most efficient way to achieve this? 
I think I would be able to get this using cycle and inside of it compare dates. But maybe there is more efficient way ? Can this could be achieved using linq or some other things which could give me the result faster/cleaner way than using cycles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines("yourPath")
            .Select(line => DateTime.ParseExact(line, 
                                   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
                                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            .GroupBy(d => d.Date)
            .SelectMany(g => new[] { g.Min(), g.Max() });
```

Comment: As the list is already sorted, it's just a waste of time to use `Min` and `Max` to get the lowest and highest values, just use `First` and `Last`.

Answer (score 1):

Group by the dates, and get the first and last line for each date. Example:

```
string[] dates = {
  "2013-05-02 07:45:15",
  "2013-05-02 09:25:01",
  "2013-05-02 18:15:15",
  "2013-05-04 08:45:15",
  "2013-05-04 17:45:35"
};

var days =
  dates.GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, 10))
  .Select(g => new { First = g.First(), Last = g.Last() });

foreach (var day in days) {
 Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", day.First, day.Last);
}
```

Output:

```
2013-05-02 07:45:15 - 2013-05-02 18:15:15
2013-05-04 08:45:15 - 2013-05-04 17:45:35
```

Comment: With no date conversion, I like it :)

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest date, you can use:

```
var latestDate = datetimeCollection.Max();
```

and for the oldest one:

```
var oldestDate = datetimeCollection.Min();
```

Take note that `datetimeCollection` is a List/Collection of `DateTime` object.

Comment: That would only get the first and last for the entire list, not the first and last for each day.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this should work.

```
  var allDates = new[] 
                { 
                    "2013-05-02 07:45:15",
                    "2013-05-02 09:25:01",
                    "2013-05-02 18:15:15",
                    "2013-05-04 08:45:15",
                    "2013-05-04 17:45:35" 
                };

            var earliest = allDates.GroupBy(date => Convert.ToDateTime(date).Day).Select(g => new
                {
                    first = g.Min(),
                    last = g.Max()
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dates = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\dates.txt").Select(o => DateTime.Parse(o));
        var res = new List<DateTime>();
        foreach (var item in (from o in dates group o by o.Date into g select g.Key))
        {
            var dummy = dates.Where(o => o.Date == item);
            res.Add(dummy.Max());
            res.Add(dummy.Min());
        }

    }
```

Comment: You already have the dates in the group, you don't need to find the dates in the collection for each group.

Comment: Yes, without that foreach it would be the same as @Cuong Le answer (the best answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can group the dates by day, then sort the group contents and get the first and last element:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        string[] fileContents = new string[] { 
                "2013-05-02 07:45:15",
                "2013-05-02 09:25:01",
                "2013-05-02 18:15:15",
                "2013-05-04 08:45:15",
                "2013-05-04 17:45:35"
            };
        List<DateTime> dates = fileContents.ToList().ConvertAll(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        foreach (var datesInSameDay in dates.GroupBy(d => d.Day)) {
            var datesList = datesInSameDay.ToList();
            datesList.Sort();
            Console.WriteLine(datesList.First());
            Console.WriteLine(datesList.Last());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**"What would be most efficient way to achieve this?"**

Since you say that the list is sorted, then we can produce the required times with a single pass through the source times.

This avoids the grouping done by all the other answers. Such grouping would be necessary if the input data was unsorted, but because it *is* sorted in ascending date/time, we do not need to explicitly group.

First, let's define a simple converter to convert the strings to `DateTime`:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> ParseTimes(IEnumerable<string> times)
{
    return times.Select(time => DateTime.ParseExact(time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Then we can write a simple method that returns the first and last time for each day (or the only time for a day if there is only one time given for that day) like so:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> FirstAndLastTimesForEachDay(IEnumerable<DateTime> times)
{
    DateTime previous = DateTime.MinValue;
    DateTime current  = DateTime.MinValue;

    foreach (var time in times)
    {
        if (previous.Date < time.Date)
        {
            if (previous != current)
                yield return previous;

            yield return time;

            current = time;
        }

        previous = time;
    }

    if (previous != current)
        yield return previous;
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
var times = new []
{
    "2013-05-02 07:45:15",
    "2013-05-02 09:25:01",
    "2013-05-02 18:15:15",
    "2013-05-03 12:34:45",
    "2013-05-04 08:45:15",
    "2013-05-04 17:45:35",
    "2013-05-05 20:00:00"
};

foreach (var time in FirstAndLastTimesForEachDay(ParseTimes(times)))
    Console.WriteLine(time);
```

Note that the implementation above only outputs a single DateTime for days that only contain a single DateTime. If instead you want the output to contain twice the single occurring DateTime for a day (so you always have a pair of DateTime per day even if the times are the same), then change the implementation to this:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> FirstAndLastTimesForEachDay(IEnumerable<DateTime> times)
{
    DateTime previous = DateTime.MinValue;

    foreach (var time in times)
    {
        if (previous.Date < time.Date)
        {
            if (previous != DateTime.MinValue)
                yield return previous;

            yield return time;
        }

        previous = time;
    }

    if (previous != DateTime.MinValue)
        yield return previous;
}
```